# Chicken Breast expiration

Tags: chicken, chicken-breast

If I buy raw chicken breasts from nofrils on June 21 and expiration date says June 23 can I cook it on June 23 and eat the left overs the next day?

Would that make the chicken okay to eat still, or should I freeze it and cook it on June 23?

Comment: Fresh chicken usually has a 'sell by' date, rather than an expiration date.

Comment: @Cindy where I live, it’s a “use by” date and government authorities recommend to discard items with a “use by” after that date - very different from the “best before” date with quite a bit of leeway.

Comment: @Stephie 'Sell by' and 'best before/by' are not the same. Here (US), stores must pull fresh products off of the shelf when they aren't sold by the 'sell by' date. Often the price is substantially reduced the day before. While stores usually pull products that are past a 'best by' date, that is a reference to quality rather than safety, and that doesn't happen so often as the products are usually sold before such a date.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy chicken on the 21st you can freeze it, and then when you defrost make sure you cook it on the same day and eat. If you want to just put it in fridge and it has expiry date of 23rd, make sure you cook it at the latest on that date. You can eat it the next day if you want as long as you've cooked it. Once cooked chicken will last in fridge for a couple of days. I usually use the rule that if I've cooked meat if it isn't eaten on the third day it gets thrown. Hope that helps. Clear as mud? Lol